# Reference for the "geometry" or "arrangements" of subspaces of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces

Inspired by Section $5$ of Chapter $1$ in Kostrikin & Manin's famous "Linear Algebra and Geometry", I am searching for a book or paper on the geometry or arrangement of subspaces in a finite-dimensional space $L$.

In "Linear Algebra and Geometry", the arrangement of single subspaces and of pairs of subspaces are studied and there they mention that there exist theories about arrangements of a larger number of subspaces, but it gets more and more combinatorially difficult as the number of subspaces goes up.

Also, I would like to know if the study of such arrangements show up in another areas in mathematics or if it is merely a combinatorial curiosity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as "hyperplane arrangement" – there is a significant literature on the subject. Certainly their significance extends beyond the combinatorial. For example, topology quickly enters in consideration of say the cohomology of an arrangement's complement. Even further, [Varchenko](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/2467) has shown a "correspondence between the representation theory of quantum groups and geometry of configurations of hyperplanes" and "connections between the representation theory of Kac-Moody Lie algebras and the geometry of configurations of hyperplanes".